# Window Perl script for appending to each line of a text file

Tags: perl, automation

I would like to know how to append to a text file using Perl in this condition.

I have a text file, the content of it is:

```
apple,123,456,orange      
cat,789,lion
```

I have a variable in a loop like this

for 1st loop:

```
my $text1 = "hi"
my $text2 = "go"
```

for 2nd loop:

```
my $text1 = "banana"
my $text2 = "car"
```

I would like to have the result in the text file

```
apple,123,456,orange,hi,banana      
cat,789,lion,go,car
```

How can I do this?

Comment: my algorithm is like this. First open and read the text file. then put the data in to array separating them by comma. Then using a temp array to store and insert the wanted strings sequently. But i emcountered a problem that the inserted string in temp array will go to next new line that i dont want.

Comment: Edit your question, insert that and add the code you're using - you'll get better answers.

Comment: Post the actual code you have, those sparse lines won't even run (missing `;` at end of lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described your problem very well and seem to be ignoring the requests for additional information. However, here's a program that matches your description and may help you

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @extra = (
    [qw/ hi go /],
    [qw/ banana car /],
);

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

for ( @extra ) {
  my ($text1, $text2) = @$_;
  $data[0] .= ",$text1";
  $data[1] .= ",$text2";
}

print "$_\n" for @data;

__DATA__
apple,123,456,orange
cat,789,lion
```

#### output

```
apple,123,456,orange,hi,banana
cat,789,lion,go,car
```

Comment: @allhksar:  Do you know any Perl at all? It's reading from the DATA file handle for testing

Comment: Sorry, I am actually new, And I see this DATA carefully, I miss yours , sorry. Many Thanks.